# Spinner & Edittext

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, spinner

i'm trying to make a simple apps but i've got a problem. i have a spinner consist of 4 string - day, date, time, location. under the spinner, there are 7checkbox of day from mon - sun, edittext of date, edittext of time and edittext of location (latitude&longitude). how to make the field of date, time and location uneditable if i choose "day" in my spinner? and vice-versa if i choose another string in spinner?? means that if i choose time, only edittext of time can be use and another 3 become uneditable. som1 plz help me, tq..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a EditText by using this:

```
EditText.setEnabled(false);
```

You need to implement `OnItemSelectedListener`, then inside your `onItemSelected` method you can switch the position:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            switch(position){
                        case 0:
                         enableAll();
                         EditText.setEnabled(false);
                        break;

                      // etc.
}
        }
```

Comment: it become uneditable, but i only want it to become uneditable when i don choose it in the spinner.

Answer (score 2):

you can can disable/enable EditText using

```
EditText.setEnabled(false);
```

or you can also  disable EditText by setting setKeyListener null as :

```
EditText.setKeyListener(null);
```

For Example :

```
private static final String[] weekitems={"day","date","time","location"};

    daySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id
            ) {

                  String strsel=weekitems[pos];
                      if(strsel.equalsIgnoreCase("day")){
                         //disable EditText here
                      }else{
                          //enable EditText here
                      } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

        }
    );
```

Comment: if i do like you suggest, it become uneditable. i want it to become uneditable when i dont choose it in the spinner.

Comment: @user1858863 : then you will need to use setOnItemSelectedListener for disable/enable EditText according to user selection

Comment: tqvm, it help but i dont know why cetrain edittext still can be edit even i use "EditText.setEnabled(false);"

Comment: @user1858863 : well so your relevant code because it's not possible to type in EditText is you have set EditText.setEnabled(false)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21619/discussion-between-user1858863-and--k)